# Rails Polymorphic Association - Join elements with similar relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I have a system that displays training resources for skills and (basically) groups of skills on my site. A user can express an interest in either a skill or a skill grouping which is stored in a polymorphic table `interests`.

I'd like to display training for each skill or skill group interest on the user home page, but in my view, only want to iterate through interests that have training (not all skills or skill groups have training).

Both `skill.rb` and the `skill_group.rb` models define a training resources relationship.

**_interests.html.erb**

```
# Currently iterate through all interests
<% @user.interests.each do |interest| %> 
  <% interest_element = interest.interest_element %>
  <% if interest_element.training_resources.size > 0 %>
    # More rendering code here...
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**interest.rb**

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interest_element, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to iterate through a limited set of interests with something like this:

```
@user.interests.joins(:interest_element => :training_resources).each do |interest|
```

but I get a `Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :interest_element` error

Is there some way I can do this type of join?

Answer (score 0):

Try @user.interests.includes(:interest_elements)
Works in rails 4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I'm no longer working on this project and can't verify it works for me. Hopefully your answer helps someone else though!